# MBProgressHUD to Singleton

Tags: objective-c, singleton, mbprogresshud

I want to set method for showing and dismissing HUD in Singleton. I write this method in singleton:

```
- (void)showHUD
{
    activityHud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] init];
    activityHud.delegate = self;
}
```

but nothing happened. For dismissing, I have no idea how to write... Any answer will be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: this does not look like Singleton pattern at all.

Comment: Because this is only method in singleton, that's not necessary to copy/paste whole singleton pattern with this method here...

Comment: You're instantiating an object and setting its delegate property. Where's the code for displaying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use static methods? I use this and put it in my util class.

```
static UIWindow *window;  
+ (MBProgressHUD *)showGlobalProgressHUDWithTitle:(NSString *)title {
window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject];
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:window animated:YES];
hud.labelText = title;

return hud;
```

}

and hide it with this :

```
+ (void)dismissGlobalHUD {

[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:window animated:YES]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do what I do. I have a base VC class that all my viewControllers subclass from and have these methods in place:

```
-(void)showActivityViewForView:(UIView *)view withActivityText:(NSString *)text;
```

and

```
-(void)hideActivityView;
```

Implemented as such:

```
    -(void)showActivityViewForView:(UIView *)view withActivityText:(NSString *)text;
{
    self.viewForActivity = view;
    self.activitytext = text;
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(showActivityView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}


-(void)showActivityView
{
    self.progressView = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.viewForActivity animated:YES];
    self.progressView.opacity = 0.5;
    self.progressView.labelText = self.activitytext;
}

-(void)hideActivityView
{
    [self.timer invalidate];
    [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];
}
```

The timer is there so that if the network activity that I do takes less than a second to complete, I don't show the `MBProgressHUD` at all.

Having it in the base class means all my VCs have easy access to these methods.